# How to unmount or remove React component after a few seconds?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a bunch of components that animate left to right and go offscreen. These components are rendered by looping through an array.

For the most part, it's working well but if I have more than a couple of these components, the view count on the Perf monitor spikes and performance tanks.

This is a sample of how I have it structured:

**Parent**

```
state = {
  myArray: []
}

<View>
  <AnimationContainer myData={this.state.myArray}  />
</View>
```

**Animation Container**

```
render() {

  return (
    <View>
      {this.props.myData.map(function(arrayItem, i) {
        return (
          <AnimatedItem key={i} arrayItem={arrayItem} />
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );

}
```

**Animated Item**

```
render() {

  return (
    <View>
      // Animated Item layout, etc.
    </View>
  );

}
```

Is it possible to unmount or remove these `AnimatedItem` components after a few seconds or when they go off screen? Is that something the `AnimatedItem` itself can trigger?

Since the amount of these components can grow dynamically, I'd like to keep this experience as smooth as possible by removing the ones that aren't in view.

Comment: How are they animating? You could update the array and remove each element once it finishes.

Comment: Can’t you pass something like an `isVisible` prop to the component you are animating to allow it to render stuff only if it is within the screen bounding box?

Comment: I managed to solve it by following Renaldo's example below. Yup, as @edu_ mentioned, I added a prop and changed state after the animation. I couldnt figure out the right place to do it but changing state in the final component did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At your last component you can do this

```
   render() {
      // have a state here 
      // const [isAnimationFinished, setIsAnimationFinished ] = useState(false)
      if(isAnimationFinished)
        return null
      return (
        <View>
          // Animated Item layout, etc.
          // when animation ends call  setIsAnimationFinished(true)
        </View>
      );

    }
```